# Not getting pre-filled state value from redux when user try to edit the form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to get the state from redux store and trying to fill the input field from state. If user in edit mode. In edit mode, we normally show the prefilled value in input field. But what is wrong with the below approach?

I am able to store single user successfully in reducer but in component i am not getting. Sometimes i get the value. Overall, it's very inconsistent.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useHistory, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { addUser, getSingleUser, updateUser } from "../redux/actions";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    marginTop: 100,
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: "45ch",
    },
  },
}));

const initialState = {
  name: "",
  address: "",
  contact: "",
  email: "",
};

const EditUser = () => {
  let { id } = useParams();
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.users);
  console.log("user", user);
  const [state, setState] = useState(user);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const { name, address, email, contact } = state;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const history = useHistory();
  let dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    setState({ ...state, [name]: value });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getSingleUser(id));
  }, []);

  const handlSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("name", name);
    if (!name || !email || !address || !contact) {
      setError("Please fill all Input Field");
    } else {
      dispatch(updateUser(state, id));
      setError("");
      history.push("/");
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Button
        style={{ width: "100px", marginTop: "20px" }}
        variant="contained"
        type="submit"
        color="secondary"
        onClick={() => history.push("/")}
      >
        Go Back
      </Button>
      <h2>Edit user</h2>
      {error && <h3 style={{ color: "red" }}>{error}</h3>}
      <form
        className={classes.root}
        noValidate
        autoComplete="off"
        onSubmit={handlSubmit}
      >
        <TextField
          id="standard-basic"
          label="Name"
          value={name}
          name="name"
          onChange={onInputChange}
          type="text"
        />
        <br />
        <TextField
          id="standard-basic"
          value={email}
          name="email"
          label="Email"
          type="email"
          onChange={onInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <TextField
          id="standard-basic"
          value={contact}
          name="contact"
          label="Contact"
          type="number"
          onChange={onInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <TextField
          id="standard-basic"
          label="Address"
          value={address}
          name="address"
          type="text    "
          onChange={onInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <Button
          style={{ width: "100px" }}
          variant="contained"
          type="submit"
          color="primary"
        >
          Update
        </Button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default EditUser;
```

Below is redux actions logic to get the single user and dispatching an action to store single user value in reducer.

```
export const getSingleUser = (id) => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    axios
      .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/${id}`)
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log("resp", resp);
        dispatch(singleUser(resp.data));
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };
};
```

Comment: Try not to render the component until the data is loaded. You get user as an async action but I don't see you have a loading status anywhere in your component.

Comment: I thought to avoid that one. But I think it will be solve problem after adding

Comment: What actions are dispatched (redux devtools confirmed, not just guessed), what changes did these actions make (redux devtools and reducer code) and how is that data selected from your component that uses the data? The only thing in your question is the selector.